# Consume mono Web Service with LabVIEW

Tags: web-services, mono, labview

I have developed a web service in mono. I can consume it in my network and with other programs. The webservice is running on an xsp2 server:

Now I import the wsdl to LabVIEW, everything goes well but when I call the webservice I get the following error.

> Error calling method
>
> TestWebService.TestWebService.Parameter(System.ArgumentNullException:
>   The key must not be NULL, parametername: key) 
>   **System.ArgumentNullExceptioin** in TestWebService.lvlib:Parameter.vi

I have looked on msdn and everything is about an svc file that I can't find in my mono ws.

Comment: How does your LabVIEW code look like? And what is the WSDL. Also check out how to create a nullable .net datatype with LabVIEW: http://tononlabview.blogspot.nl/2012/03/labview-web-services-and-optional.html

Comment: Hi! The WSDL is an auto-generated WSDL with mono or vs. I saw the blog and I'm getting the same error even with strings, for example: 
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="HelloWorldResult" type="s:string"/> I get the same exception when I try to call the operation HelloWorld of the service. I can't show you the LabVIEW code because I'm the part programming the web services and I don't have a license of LabView, I have to ask the other software engineer for that. Thanks in advice!.

Comment: So you're LabVIEW-engineer should use a string (a string can be nullable by default). The WSDL importer of LabVIEW cannot deal really good with optional inputs, you have to reprogram some of the lower level functions.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need a 'Key' which is not NULL, is there a 'CreateKey' method? Or you should just use some arbitrary number.

Ton

Comment: Hi! Thank you! I have send the information to the LabVIEW-engineer and I'm waiting her response. There is no parameter, or method with key string on them that's the weird point.

Comment: Hi,this link has the image with the webservice in LabView http://i49.tinypic.com/2uerbc5.png